# Accessing a static member unordered_map via operator[]

Tags: c++

Being quite green with C++, I ran into behavior I don't quite understand, and haven't been able to find an explanation even with intense googling, so I was hoping someone could explain what exactly is wrong here.

```cpp
// test.h

#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::unordered_map<int, int> test_type;

class test
{
public:
    static const test_type tmap;
};


// test.cpp

#include "test.h"

const test_type test::tmap = {
    { 1, 1 }
};


// main.cpp

#include "test.h"

int main()
{   
   // Attempt 1: access key via operator[]
   std::cout << test::tmap[1];

   // Attempt 2: access key via at()
   std::cout << test::tmap.at(1);

   return 0;
}
```

If I have Attempt 1 in my code, Visual Studio's compiler insists I'm using a binary `[` operator that hasn't been defined, but that doesn't really make sense to me because as far as I know there is no binary `[` operator, (braces are always unary, right?).

So, why doesn't Attempt 1 work?

Comment: The braces are binary, the first parameter is the unordered_map, and the second is the key (1).

Comment: _"if I define the map outside of a class, the operator[] method works as expected"_ Does it? Are you sure?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, yes: http://cpp.sh/4dab

Comment: @Schlaus: The link is not working.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually nevermind, I just realized my non-class map wasn't `const`, so yes, it was working, but only because it wasn't the same thing in the first place. D'oh.

Comment: @Schlaus: I suspected as much :P

Comment: @MagikM18 Really? All the definitions I can find for `operator[]` are unary, take for example this one from `unordered_map`: `mapped_type& operator[] ( key_type&& k );`

Comment: That's still a *member*operator, which always takes one hidden `this` operand.

Comment: Exactly - the `this` is the first parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) is not `const`, because it inserts the specified key to the map if it doesn't already exist.  Since it is not `const` you cannot use it with a `const` object.  [`std::unordered_map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) does have a `const` overload so it compiles.  You either need to make `test` non-`const` or just use the `at()` function.

Comment: Better to say `const` than "constant". The latter may imply expectations that do not match the former, which has distinct, specific and well-defined semantics.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something simple that I overlooked. Thanks!